# Replace randomly occuring and grouped zeros with last non-zero number from the column above

Tags: libreoffice, calc

I'm trying to ultimately generate a cell containing text saying what the ranking of a data element from a data set is.

e.g. I'm trying to achieve :

"Joint 1st of 31"

"Joint 1st of 31"

"Joint 1st of 31"

"4th of 31"

etc.

Generating the first number of that string is the only problem I have.

Cells in right hand column AG are to check if a zero is encountered to the left in column AF.

If a zero is found then read **UP** column AF and grab the last non-zero number and write it out at the appropriate place in AG.
So in column AG I should have
1
1
1
4
5
6
6
8
8
8
...

I really need a formula like
=if(AF{row}=0,<AF{upwards from {row} until non-zero found>)

Is there a named function to achieve this?
Tq. in advance for any input.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it sussed! In AG8 enter the following formula....

=IF(AF8=0,AG7,AF8)

Took best part of a day. Seems so easy now but only became apparent after many, many attempts. Seems rather 'hacky' too but hey, if it works... :D